# Duplicate record cause no record insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, c#-6.0

Please consider this scenario:

I have two tables: `Temp` and `Convert`. The structure of these 2 tables are exactly same. I want to do some operation on each record of `Temp` and add it to `Convert` table. By doing my work, there may be duplicate records in `Convert` table and so I don't want to insert that record in `Convert` table. I wrote this code:

```
foreach (var item in allRecords)
{
    var converted = new Convert()
    {
        F1 = item.F1,
        F2 = item.F2,
        F3 = DoWork(F3),
    };

    try
    {
        context.Convert.AddObject(converted);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var msg = "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Convert'." 
                  + " Cannot insert duplicate key":

        if (ex.InnerException.Message.Contains(msg))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
             throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is when I get exception for first duplicate and `continue` command executed, it seems that duplicate record not discard and still wait for save. After first exceptionو No record is stored in the database because of my first duplicate error. How I can solve this issue without checking existence of duplicate error in `Convert` table?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate? it is duplicate when all fields are the same?

Comment: @uɐʞɥsɐ I think it is no matters. Consider the `F3` is my primary key

Comment: ORMs are *not* suitable for data copying. What could be a simple `INSERT Target SELECT ... from Source left join target on Source.ID=Target.ID where Target.ID is null` becomes a long and slow process if you have to move records one by one

Comment: Why don't you filter down `allRecords` to the ones that don't exist in `Convert`?

Comment: In this case, you are explicitly telling EF to *add* the objects. You should *attach* them instead and let EF decide whether to insert or update them. The operation will still be many times slower than an `INSERT` statement

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: This one time job and for I did it for simplicity

Comment: @Arian as you see, it's the exact opposite of simple

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You forget `DoWork` bro. In `C#` environment it is very easy to write `DoWork`

Comment: @Arian I don't. I write ETL jobs in C# for a living, using TPL  Dataflow blocks. Instead of trying to process data on a single thread, you can process records in different steps with the final one inserting them to a staging table using SqlBulkCopy. After that, an UPSERT operation can move the changes to the target table. This way you can move 100Ks of rows in the time a step-by-step ORM job would move a single 1000, if not less

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if the entity exists and if not - add it? Like this :

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
public class ContextWithExtensionExample
{
    public void DoSomeContextWork(DbContext context)
    {
        var uni = new Unicorn();
        context.Set<Unicorn>().AddIfNotExists(uni , x => x.Name == "James");
     }
}

public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class, new()
    {
        var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();
        return !exists ? dbSet.Add(entity) : null;
    }
}
```

You can use this method directly and remember to call DbContext.SaveChanges() after the call.

Answer (score 0):

```
var converted = new Convert()
    {
        F1 = item.F1,
        F2 = item.F2,
        F3 = DoWork(F3),
    };
```

As F3 is your primarykey, then just check if it exists before inserting:

```
if(context.Convert.Any(x => x.F3 == converted.F3)
{
    //deal with the error
}
else
{
     context.Convert.AddObject(converted);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```